# Reset select field on select with select2

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to reset a select field like this

```
$('#name').change(function(){
  $('#name2').val( $('#name2').prop('defaultSelected') );
});
```

But this dosen't work on select2..

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/weg82/) how I want it to look like and work like it!

And this should be the new one.. http://jsfiddle.net/js3vV/

Comment: well? it works... (FF + CH)

Comment: Yes, it works on JSFiddle.. but not on my website.

Answer (score 0):

Add `defaultSelected` attribute in second dropdown to set default selected  value of dropdown , it will allow to return  `$('#name2').prop('defaultSelected')` default value of dropdown,which will reset second dropdown on change in first dropdown.

```
<select id="name2" defaultSelected="">
<option value="">select all</option>
<option value="1">Text 1</option>
<option value="2">Text 2</option>
<option value="3">Text 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   $('#name').change(function(){
  $('#name2').val( $('#name2').prop('defaultSelected') );
});
$('#name2').change(function(){
  $('#name').val( $('#name').prop('defaultSelected') );
});
```

add one function for that, I tested that, I think it worked.
here ur fiddle, 
[image]

`

Comment: No, only when #name is change! :)

Comment: This code works on jsfiddle.. but not on my website.. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7P3f5/)

Comment: Yes, But Im just show you guys an example. I Set up a jsfiddle quick with some simple code :)

Comment: If you want to check it live, go ahead! :) 
[link](http://www.unikabutiker.nu/hitta-unika-butiker/) the map is half done..

Comment: I can't choose the data from below box,so how can I test.ur map is, must choose upper box first ,right???

Comment: Yes, The upper box must choose first. Then I want to choose the below box. And then if I edit the Upperbox I want the lowerbox reset.

Comment: Yes,when I want to rechoose the upper box to "Valj Stad/Ort", I can't find that. So I think that will be problem. Changes from two boxes is really nice. But If u want "Valj Butik", u must create "Valj Stad/Ort" for that and must choose.

Comment: in JSFiddle , u can rechoose "select all", right??, u can get default selected for both too. They are pairs

Comment: Okey! Thanks Lady Ivory. I Will test.

Comment: One more, U r boxes are created to change for when Upper box changed, the lower will be changed data automatically,right?. That was so great. but Break that concept and indicate "Valj Butik" for all data. that will be work, I think. Thank you :D